# MariaDB Exception Invalid utf8mb3 character string: 'ACED00'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb, mysql-event

I am writing a native query and keep getting the "Invalid utf8mb3 character string: 'ACED00'" error. Here is my query

```
   @Query(value = "select " +
            "(case when bh.type in :writeOff then 'WRITE_OFF' " +
            "when bh.type in :refund then 'RETURN' end) as sector," +
            "sum(bh.amount) as size " +
            "from `phedon_balance_history` bh " +
            "where(bh.type in :writeOff or bh.type in :refund) " +
            "and(bh.status = :status) " +
            "and ((:startDate is null) or bh.creation_date between :startDate and :endDate) " +
            "group by (case when bh.type in :writeOff then 'WRITE_OFF' " +
            "when bh.type in :refund then 'RETURN'end)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<CommissionProjection> findCommissionStatistic(List<BalanceType> writeOff, List<BalanceType> refund, BalanceTransactionStatus status,
                                                       LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate);
```

I have tried changing the MariaDB version also tried to change the encoding in the dialect, however nothing helps, where is the issue?

Comment: How does the generated sql look like? And can you execute it in a SQL editor?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same exception when I was trying to use an enum value as a parameter.

```
public List<A> fetchByType(SomeTypeEnum type) {
    List<A> query = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(
        "SELECT * FROM a WHERE some_type = :type",
        Map.of("type", type), // SqlException here
        this::mapRow
    );
    return query;
}
```

The simple solution was to use `toString` and the problem was solved:

```
Map.of("type", type.toString())
```